# What is in helm's values.yaml equivalent of a k8s manifest's nfs-volume?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, microk8s

I am just learning helm charts and want to slowly migrate my manifest to helm.

As far as I have understood, `values.yaml` is the way to get a chart customized. My current manifest contains PV's using the nfs-volumes like this:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: linuxserver/ddclient
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ddclient
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config
          name: ddclient-config
      volumes:
      - name: ddclient-config
        nfs:
          path: /home/main/ddclient
          server: 10.0.0.101
```

How would I go about setting up (considering the example above) `/home/main/ddclient` in `values.yaml` ? Does anybody have tutorials or examples?

Comment: A values file contains specific configuration for the chart, and how it's used depends on the chart's template code.  It does not usually contain complete resources, and it is not a path to perform arbitrary modification of the generated YAML.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a renderer function in your helper:

```
{{- define "application.tplvalues.render" -}}
{{- tpl (.value | toYaml) .context }}
{{- end -}}
```

then in your chart:

```
{{- if .Values.application.volumes }}
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.application.volumes  }}
      - name: {{ $key }}
{{ include "application.tplvalues.render" ( dict "value" $value "context" $ ) | indent 12 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and then in values, you can have:

```
volumes:
    ddclient-config:
      configMap:
        nfs:
          path: /home/main/ddclient
          server: 10.0.0.101
```

For a very good base of the helm chart, you can use [this skeleton](https://github.com/stakater/application/).